# Issue with labeling in ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on some code in R using ggplot and I need to label only certain numbers on my graph. With how I have things set up right now, the code will leave everything blank on the chart except for the ones that are labeled "1". I want all of the numbers in that list to be labeled though, and none of them except whichever one is first are being labeled. I tried using `as.character(genotypes)`, rearranging the ifelse statement, and using `c()`. Does anybody know why this is happening and how I can get the graph to include all of the numbers I want to label on the columns? For reference, the fill part does work. Thanks!

Note that this isn't the exact code I'm actually working with. I can't post that code here but this replicate does -mostly- what the actual one does.

```r
genotypes <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5) 
genotypes

freq <- table(genotypes)
freq

haplotypes <- c("AA", "AB", "BB")
haplotypes

length(freq) <- length(genotypes)
length(haplotypes) <- length(genotypes)

df <- data.frame(genotypes, freq, haplotypes)
df

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = haplotypes, y = freq
           , fill = ifelse(freq >= 2, reorder(as.character(genotypes), desc(freq)), "grey")
           , label = ifelse(as.numeric(genotypes) == 1 & 2, as.character(genotypes), element_blank()))) +
  geom_col(position = "stack", show.legend = FALSE, color = "black") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("AA","AB","BB", NA)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = as.vector(cols25())) +
  xlab("Resistance Genotype") +
  ylab("Samples (n)") +
  ggtitle("Genotypes by Year and Status") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

I tried using `as.character(genotypes)`, rearranging the `ifelse` statement, and using `c()`.

When I tried using `as.character(genotypes) == c("1", "2")`, it only labeled some of the columns that it should have with 1 or 2.

When I tried using `as.numeric(genotypes) == c(1 & 2)`, it didn't label any of the boxes.

When I tried using `as.numeric(genotypes) == 1 | 2`, it labeled all boxes. When I tried using `as.numeric(genotypes) == c(1 | 2)`, it didn't label any of the boxes.

When I tried using `as.numeric(genotypes) == 1 && 2`, none of the boxes were labeled.

When I tried using `as.numeric(genotypes) == 1 || 2`, all of the boxes were labeled with the number 2 (including the ones that shouldn't be labeled with 2).

When I tried using either `&&` or `||` in a `c()` they both made all of the boxes blank.

I also tried using `!=` instead to rearrange the `ifelse` statement, but that usually produced the opposite results as above.

Update: correct solution is `as.character(genotypes) %in% ("1", "2")`

Comment: Can you please include a reproducible example? Share some data in the question using `dput()` , and make sure the code you've provided creates a plot - it looks like some parts of your ggplot code are missing.

Comment: Sorry I'm having a little trouble doing that haha. The original code is for a research project and I can't release it yet but I can't get a simpler version of the code (the one above) to actually work but I'm working on it

Comment: The code you've provided has a random `element_blank()` inside your call to `ggplot()` - at the moment, we don't even know what type of chart you're making. Can you create an example using some other data e.g. with `mtcars` that recreates a similar problem? Without code or data, it's difficult to help. I would perhaps suggest using `mutate()` to add labels and fill colours to your dataframe before passing into ggplot2 if you're using complex conditions.

Comment: Try `ggplot(data = matrix, aes(x = haplotypes, y = freq, fill = ifelse(freq >= 2, reorder(as.character(genotypes), desc(freq)), "grey"),
                          label = ifelse(as.numeric(genotypes) != 1, as.character(genotypes), ""))) 
`

Comment: genotypes <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5) 
genotypes

freq <- table(genotypes)
freq

haplotypes <- c("AA", "AB", "BB")
haplotypes

length(freq) <- length(genotypes)
length(haplotypes) <- length(genotypes)

df <- data.frame(genotypes, freq, haplotypes)
df

Comment: ggplot(data = df, aes(x = haplotypes, y = freq
           , fill = ifelse(freq >= 2, reorder(as.character(genotypes), desc(freq)), "grey")
           , label = ifelse(as.numeric(genotypes) == 1 & 2, as.character(genotypes), element_blank()))) +
  geom_col(position = "stack", show.legend = FALSE, color = "black") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("AA","AB","BB", NA)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = as.vector(cols25())) +
  xlab("Resistance Genotype") +
  ylab("Samples (n)") +

Comment: ggtitle("Genotypes by Year and Status") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) 

That's a full version that roughly does what the actual code does

Comment: @Julien that does work, it's just when I try to do more than one number there is when it doesn't work

Comment: Please do not post data and code in comments, [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76722532/edit) instead.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using stack overflow, I don't code very often and I'm not very good at it

Comment: `as.character(genotypes) %in% c("1", "2")`

Comment: That worked @Julien thank you so much!! I was struggling with this for days so I really appreciate it

Comment: `as.character(genotypes) %in% 1:2` would work too